# Limit Number of Taxonomy Terms (Images) Displayed

Tags: plugins, custom-taxonomy, attachments, terms, limit

Getting some issues with [taxonomy images plugin](http://wordpress.org/plugins/taxonomy-images/).I am trying to limit the number of taxonomy terms displayed on a page to 6. The following code is what I'm working with. It shows the term name and image attachment. Tips on how to limit the number of terms/images?

```
<?php
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array(
            'taxonomy' => 'technologies',
        ) );
        if ( ! empty( $terms ) ) {
            print "\n" . '<div class="row">';
            foreach( (array) $terms as $term ) {
                print "\n" . '<div class="col-lg-2 col-md-2 col-sm-4 col-xs-6">';
                print "\n\t" . wp_get_attachment_image($term->image_id, array('600', '600'), "", array("class" => "img-responsive tech-logo" )  ); 
                print "\n\t" . '<h6 class="tech-description text-center">' . esc_html( $term->name ) . '</h6>';
                print "\n" . '<span class="hidden-lg hidden-md"><br/><br/></span></div>';
            }
            print "\n" . '</div>';
        }
?>
```

Comment: You can read  [how to limit foreach loop to three loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8765879/how-to-limit-foreach-loop-to-three-loops)

Answer (score 1):

The filter uses the third parameter as an array that gets passed to `get_terms()`, which you're already using to specify the taxonomy to query. Looking at the [`get_terms()` documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/), you can see there's a 'number' argument that you can pass to limit the number of terms returned. This is what you want to use.

Your use of the filter now becomes

```
$terms = apply_filters( 'taxonomy-images-get-terms', '', array(
    'taxonomy'  => 'technologies',
    'term_args' => array(
        'number' => 6,
    ),
) );
```

When the filter is applied, `$terms` should now be limited to a max of 6 terms.

**UPDATE:**

The plugin is using a deprecated argument for `get_terms()`, which pre-4.5 took two parameters: the taxonomy string and an array of options. That options array is defined as [`$term_args`](https://plugins.trac.wordpress.org/browser/taxonomy-images/tags/0.9.7/public-filters.php#L80) in the plugin. As long as that's in there, you'll need to pass an array with 'taxonomy', and 'term_args[]' passed separately instead of in the same array as `get_terms()` expects them to be after WP 4.5.

Comment: Hi @morganestes, thanks for your reply. I also looked at this and thought it would have been a solution, but it doesn't seem to be working for some reason.  Further thoughts?

Comment: The plugin you're using is passing arguments to `get_terms()` using a deprecated argument. Until that is fixed, you need to pass your args as part of the 'term_args' array key. I've updated my code to reflect the change needed.

Comment: Well, that did limit it to 6, however the update no longer shows just the terms applying to the post. It shows 6 terms, all the same, alphabetically.

Comment: I think for that you need to contact their support team https://wordpress.org/support/plugin/taxonomy-images